# from data import DataSet

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, dataset

I'm trying to replicate some Python code on a Github website. I'm running `Python3.6.8` in a conda environment.

```
import numpy as np
import os.path
from data import DataSet
```

I get the Error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extract_features.py", line 16, in <module>
    from data import DataSet
ImportError: cannot import name 'DataSet'
```

I am not sure which module is causing this error. `python -c "import data"` gives no error.

Comment: It would be nice if we could take a look at the code. Past the github repo you are using.

Comment: Probably, it should be 'from data import Data'.

Comment: Sure, the repo is at https://github.com/harvitronix/five-video-classification-methods. After extracting the images from the videos, I am running extract_features.py where I get this error. Thanks.

Comment: Have you put data.py file to a directory where you run your script?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, sorry for the confusion, thanks for the help.